# Linear projection library C#

Tags: c#, math

I'm working on a project and I am in need to use a linear projection technique such as the fourier motzkin elimination. But as I tried to find a suitable implementation for c# I was unable to find one. The only implementation I found is in c or c++ called porta (produced in 1993). It would mean that I would need to see how I will edit the code so that I'll be able to port it to C# and use it as a dll. By any chance is there any numerical or math library for C# available to do linear projection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [ILNumerics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILNumerics.Net). Code is in [SourceForge](http://ilnumericsnet.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ilnumericsnet/) with examples. Not sure if there is an implementation of Fourier Motzkin though.

Some others are listed here in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#.NET_Framework_languages_C.23.2C_F.23_and_VB.NET)

Edit-
There is also a more recent implementation of Fourier Motzkin in C, with an example in python. - http://code.google.com/p/fm-eliminator/

If nothing work's out, you can just port this to C# and publish it (preferably as a contribution to one of the open source libraries).

Edit 2 - 
Found a few implementations in Matlab. One example [here](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7957-fourier-motzkin-elimination/content/fourmotz/fourmotz.m)

Now, there is this tool called [Matlab Builder NE](http://www.mathworks.in/products/netbuilder/) (which comes with a trial) that promises that you can build .NET or COM components from a Matlab program.

Comment: unfortuatley ILNumerics does not contain such function, will check some of the others listed on wiki. But i guess ill have to port it as a dll :/. None the less thanks for the help.

Comment: @AdrianDeBarro - another update - found a way you could get a Matlab program and compile it to a .net library. You would need to try and see.

Comment: yes i did find that one was looking at it and thought to try and do an implementation myself if everything else fails